# Can you (briefly) have a real, non-zero infinitesimal?

Tags: real-numbers, infinity, rational-numbers, infinitesimals

Suppose you have the set of the rationals between 0 and 1, let's call it $\mathbb{Q}_1$. Now I want the probability of choosing a number in $\mathbb{Q}_1$ and getting 1/2. If I add this to the probability of getting every other rational in $\mathbb{Q}_1$ e.g. 1/3, 0, 2/7 ... (which would each be the same as getting 1/2 in $\mathbb{Q}_1$) then I should get back 1 because I'm basically asking what is the probability of choosing a rational in $\mathbb{Q}_1$ and getting back a rational in $\mathbb{Q}_1$.

The probability of getting 1/2 from $\mathbb{Q}_1$ must then be non-zero and must be equal to 1 / the countably infinite. This is an infinitesimal probability, but does not exist within $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this maths correct?

Comment: In probability theory, just because an event can happen, doesn't mean it has nonzero probability.

Comment: You assert that each rational has the same probability.  This assumption is not compatible with the notions of probability used in mathematics today.

Comment: @GEdgar How would they differ then?

Comment: Modern probability is based on measure theory,  a set of events with 0 measure has probability 0.   There's lots of nonempty sets with measure 0.   If you want infinitesimals,  you have to work in a non-Archimedean field, and things get seriously weird there

Comment: To talk about "choosing randomly", you must specify a probability distribution on the set of things you are choosing from, or in other words a probability measure.  You haven't done so, so the question is not answerable.  It sounds like you are thinking about a "uniform" distribution in which all numbers are equally likely to be chosen, but such a distribution simply doesn't exist, basically for the reason you state - every individual number would have probability zero, and countably many zeros don't add up to 1.